# How to split a String by escaping text which are in double-quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to split an input comma separated string and store the result in an array.

Following works great

```
arr=inputString.split(",")
```

for this example

```
 John, Doe       =>arr[0]="John"      arr[1]="Doe"
```

But it fail to get following expected output

```
"John, Doe", Dan  =>arr[0]="John, Doe" arr[1]="Dan"
 John, "Doe, Dan" =>arr[0]="John"      arr[1]="Doe, Dan"
```

Following regex too didn't help

```
        var regExpPatternForDoubleQuotes="\"([^\"]*)\"";
        arr=inputString.match(regExpPatternForDoubleQuotes);
        console.log("txt=>"+arr)
```

The String could contain more than two double-quotes.

I am trying above in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for link. Didn't know it was already answered. But the linked answered is very verbose and good one. The answer here is quick and short. I prefer the latter in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
var re = /[ ,]*"([^"]+)"|([^,]+)/g;
var match;
var str = 'John, "Doe, Dan"';
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    console.log(match[1] || match[2]);
}
```

How it works:

```
/
    [ ,]*     # The regex first skips whitespaces and commas
    "([^"]+)" # Then tries to match a double-quoted string
    |([^,]+)  # Then a non quoted string
/g            # With the "g" flag, re.exec will start matching where it has
              # stopped last time
```

Try here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5wvY/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this pattern with the *exec* method:

```
/(?:"[^"]*"|[^,]+)+/g
```